# Java can't show image [CANVAS]

Tags: java, image, canvas

I am currently making a game in Java and I am trying to draw an image on my screen, but nothing show up ( only a black screen but no errors ) :(

Here is the code to import the image:

```
public static Bitmap loadBitmap(String fileName) {
    try {
        BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(Art.class.getResource(fileName));

        int w = img.getWidth();
        int h = img.getHeight();

        Bitmap result = new Bitmap(w, h);
        img.getRGB(0, 0, w, h, result.pixels, 0, w);
        for (int I = 0; I < result.pixels.length; i++) {
            int in = result.pixels[i];
            int col = (in & 0xf) >> 2;
            if (in == 0xffff00ff) col = -1;
            result.pixels[i] = col;
        }
        return result;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

And the Bitmap class:

```
public void draw(Bitmap bitmap, int xOffs, int yOffs)
{
    for(int y = 0; y < bitmap.height; y++)
    {
        int yPix = y + yOffs;       
        if(yPix < 0 || yPix >= height) continue;

        for(int x = 0; x < bitmap.width; x++)
        {
            int xPix = x + xOffs;
            if(xPix < 0 || xPix >= width) continue;

            int alpha = bitmap.pixels[x + y * bitmap.width];

            if(alpha > 0)
                pixels[xPix + yPix * width] = bitmap.pixels[x + y * bitmap.width];
        }
    }
}
```

And to draw all of this :

```
public void render(Game game)
{

    for(int y = 0; y < height; y++)
    {
        float yd = ((y + 0.5f) - height / 2.0f) / height;

        if(yd < 0) yd *= -1;

        float z = 10 / yd;

        for(int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            float xd = (x - width / 2.0f) / height;

            xd *= z;
            int xx = (int) (xd) & 7;
            int yy = (int) (z + game.time * 0.1f) & 7;

            pixels[x + y * width] = Art.floors.pixels[xx + yy * 64];
        }
    }
}
```

I have no errors! I don't really understand.. is this a bug caused by alpha or something? Ho and my image.png is 64x64 made in paint.net

Comment: Are you sure that image is located where you think it is? Try stepping through this with a debugger, or at least add some print statements, to figure out when the program's execution differs from your expectations. Otherwise, please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and we'll go from there.

Comment: But if the location was wrong, there would be a input error no ?

Comment: Probably. Then again I don't see any drawing code, so it's hard to tell you what's going on without that MCVE.

Comment: I will give you the workspace (only 6 classes) and you will be able to see what is going on here, give me a sec to upload it :p

Comment: Please don't. We don't really have time to debug entire projects like that. That's why we ask for an MCVE instead.